# Family Tree make center and responsive

Tags: css, laravel-5.4

Hello everyone I need your help to center screen and responsive this family 
tree. Please see the link below. Thank you.

My Code Is As Follow

```css
/*Now the CSS*/
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

.tree ul {
 padding-top: 20px; position: relative;
 
 transition: all 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
 float: left; text-align: center;
 list-style-type: none;
 position: relative;
 padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
 
 transition: all 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before, .tree li::after{
 content: '';
 position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
 border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
 width: 50%; height: 20px;
}
.tree li::after{
 right: auto; left: 50%;
 border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/
.tree li:only-child::after, .tree li:only-child::before {
 display: none;
}

/*Remove space from the top of single children*/
.tree li:only-child{ padding-top: 0;}

/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/
.tree li:first-child::before, .tree li:last-child::after{
 border: 0 none;
}
/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
.tree li:last-child::before{
 border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.tree li:first-child::after{
 border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/
.tree ul ul::before{
 content: '';
 position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%;
 border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
 width: 0; height: 20px;
}

.tree li a{
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 padding: 5px 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #666;
 font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
 font-size: 11px;
 display: inline-block;
 
 border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 
 transition: all 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*Time for some hover effects*/
/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/
.tree li a:hover, .tree li a:hover+ul li a {
 background: #c8e4f8; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}
/*Connector styles on hover*/
.tree li a:hover+ul li::after, 
.tree li a:hover+ul li::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::before{
 border-color:  #94a0b4;
}

/*Thats all. I hope you enjoyed it.
Thanks :)*/
```

```html
<!--
We will create a family tree using just CSS(3)
The markup will be simple nested lists
-->
<div class="tree">
 <ul>
  <li>
   <a href="#">Parent</a>
   <ul>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Child</a>
     <ul>
      <li>
       <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Child</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a></li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
       <ul>
        <li>
         <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
        </li>
       </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```